# Preventing duplicate entries in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I got problem here with my C# code..

What I want to do with this code is, that when I type something from textbox with the same symbols (the same name), it shows, that I can't add it in the listbox two or more times.
So I made this code:

```
void Btn_addClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string thelist = listBox1.Text;
    string text = textBox1.Text;

    if(text == thelist) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This name already exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }   
}
```

But the problem is, that it shows the MessageBox only if I select the name from the list and compare it from text box. If I don't select anything or other word, it adds the same word without telling that it already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to compare your `TextBox.Text` to the entire `ListBox`.  You probably want to find out if the `ListBox` *contains* the text you are entering.

The following will achieve the results you want very easily:

```
void Btn_addClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.Items.Contains(textBox1.Text)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This name already exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all Items in the ListBox to identify the duplicate items

Try This:

```
void Btn_addClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    string text = textBox1.Text;
    bool isDuplicate = false;

    foreach (var name in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if(name.ToString().Equals(text))
        {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isDuplicate) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show("This name already exists!");
    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Good, but you can make this much more simple by just using `listBox1.Items.Contains()`

Comment: . . . This is efficient, but harder then it needs to be: Why create a `bool` when you could use a `.contains`? :D